# What is needed to set up a RemoteApp for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remoteapp

In Windows 7 I discovered the possibility to add RemoteApps. They require a link starting with https:// and so on.

How can I create a RemoteApp for me to use? Is it possible for me to make an application running on my desktop computer a RemoteApp so that I can use it from my laptop for example?

I have Windows 7 on both the desktop and laptop. Have tried to find info about it, but haven't been successful... is RemoteApps something that can only be created on a machine running Windows Server 2008 maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Deploying Personal Virtual Desktops by Using RemoteApp and Desktop Connection Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941616(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: So Windows Server 2008 R2 is needed for the serving part then it seems. Oh well... thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 9):

Good news is you no longer need Windows Server 2008 R2.  With RDP 7.0 now released, and if you apply the required updates for Windows Vista SP1 and Windows XP SP3 you can now use RemoteApp to remote and/or virtual machines running Windows Vista or Windows XP.

These machines can be running as virtual machines under VirtualBox or VMWare Worksation/Player, not just under Hyper-V.

It's a bit lengthy, so I've documented how to enable RemoteApp connections in a blog post, [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117115603/http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2009/12/18/137048.aspx).

Basically, on the client you have to hand edit the RDP file to set remote application mode and nominate the remote application you wish to run. On the guest/remote system you need to add the relevant registry keys to support that named application and permit access.

Using RDP 7.0 with multi monitor support for RemoteApp has the advantage that the floating application window can be placed on any monitor on your system.

Comment: This has some awesome potential. I could not get this to work with a XP guest,  as I see neither have you or some of your readers. I'd love to hear what you find out!

Comment: Thanks for the info I am just thinking about trying VS2010 as a remote app from a slowish laptop.

Comment: Can I host a remote app directly from a Windows 7 box (that is not a VM)?

Comment: (I know this is an old comment above, but) yes, you certainly can. Use the 'RemoteApp Tool' that is now linked to from the Updates section at the top of the article pointed to above to configure your apps and generate RDP files for them... works a treat!

Comment: @JohnRix ironic that the initials of "RemoteApp Tool" are [RAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_access_trojan)