# How to do Seamless Virtualization with Ubuntu, KVM and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, remote-desktop, virtualization, ubuntu-10.04

I run Ubuntu-10.04 (Lucid Lynx) as my primary operating system. I have a KVM Windows7 VM which I use to run a Internet Explorer and a couple of other Windows only applications that I need.

I would like to use RDP to integrate these applications seamlessly into my Ubuntu desktop rather than having to use them within the KVM Console. I've been running through the instructions on the Ubuntu site but have had no success: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SeamlessVirtualization

Essentially, when I invoke rdesktop I still get the full Windows desktop rather than just the one application I'm trying to launch. I suspect this is related to the fact that it's a Windows7 VM rather than an XP VM as used in those instructions.

Does anyone know how to get seamless RDP working with Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That capability is referred to as RemoteApp and is part of the Windows Server architecture. See: [What is needed to set up a RemoteApp for Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/17924/what-is-needed-to-set-up-a-remoteapp-for-windows-7)

Also, [SeamlessRDP](http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/) might be an option. I've never used it, so I cannot speak from experience.

Comment: Thanks, Ironically I no longer have the windows VM I could use this with, but that looks like exactly what I was looking for at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VirtualBox on a Linux host with a bunch of various guests.

Once you install guest additions in a Windows guest, you will have
seamless mouse, display integration and for me it works very good.

VirtualBox is completely free and you can find it here:

http://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of Virtual Box and do use that as well. What I'm really after is the ability to have a single application (e.g. Internet Explorer) visible within my Ubuntu desktop as if it was a native application, or a remote X application. I believe from the linked page that this is possible with Remote Desktop.

VBox's seamless mode is close but just replaces the background with the host desktop which is a not quite what I'm after. E.g. there's a single task bar icon for VBox rather than one Per Application.

Comment: @edc In that case you could run windows explorer in WINE. Oh wait, IE is coupled directly with the Windows OS... If you were talking about (just about) any application **but** IE it could be installed to run natively in Ubuntu. In this case IE is the rare exception and you won't be able to use it standalone without Windows so you're stuck with vbox/kvm. I don't know about vbox, but you can always run kvm in full-screen mode. That's about the best you're gonna get.

Answer (score 1):

You can get IE running in Linux by making user of the instructions at http://www.tatanka.com.br/ or google for IEs4Linux