# How to set up limited access remote control to a specific program?

Tags: windows-7, security, remote-desktop, remote-access, kiosk

I have a certain program running on a Windows 7 PC and I want a group of people to be able to access it and use the program remotely.

However, these remote users shouldn't have any other permissions (e.g. to make changes to the local operating system or use other programs on the PC).

The users should be able to log in without a confirmation given each time on my PC. Also, some of the remotes users are on PCs and others are on Macs.

What setup (preferably a free solution, but not necessarily) can provide such access?

Comment: IMO, as-is this question is too broad, and bordering on a product request.  Having said that, check into RemoteApp: [Overview of RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc755055.aspx)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it's more or less the PC version of this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125603/allow-access-to-a-single-application-only-when-accessing-remotely

Comment: That question speaks to users at the console being limited to one program (like a Kiosk), where-as your question specifically talks about _remote_ access.  So which is it? If you're talking about a local console kiosk, then there's MANY questions on here related to that already, what have you tried already?  If you want them RDPing into the system from remote, but only accessing 1 program, then RemoteApp fits the bill.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 first of all RemoteApp isn't for Win7 as far as I can tell. Secondly, I'm looking for a combined solution.

Comment: Officially your supposed to use a Server OS for RemoteApp, but see this SU question: [What is needed to set up a RemoteApp for Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/17924/what-is-needed-to-set-up-a-remoteapp-for-windows-7).  If you ALSO want people to log onto the console, please edit your question you explain that as well.  But really, this question is pretty broad as-is, and (again) seems like a "tell me what software does X" question, which is off-topic.  Pick some stuff, start implementing it, and when you get stuck come back with specific questions about specific problems. Good luck!

Comment: IIRC this can be done using a combination of remote-desktop and parental controls in Windows 7. However, I cannot verify as I do not have access to a win computer right now. Parental controls can specify which programs a standard (non-admin) user can run.